# Func<T extends IComponent>( ): T[] => IComponent[] - doesn't assign to T

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I trying to realize ECS pattern in typescript, and i created class `ComponentStore` which contain components of entities for next handling.
Components like this:

```js
class Health implements IComponent {
  name: EComponents = EComponents.health;
}
```

But methods `setComponent` and `getComponents` throw errors:

> Error:(12, 11) TS2322: Type 'IComponent[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
>    Type 'IComponent' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>
> Error:(17, 5) TS2322: Type 'IComponent[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
>    Type 'IComponent' is not assignable to type 'T'.

I do this like in example in [Generics in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), but it doesn't work.

```js
class ComponentStore implements IComponentStore {
  private components: Map<EComponents, IComponent[]> = new Map();

  setComponent<T extends IComponent>( componentName: EComponents, component: IComponent): void {
    const components: T[] = this.components.get(componentName) || [];
    this.components.set(componentName, [...components, component ]);
  }

  getComponents<T extends IComponent>( componentName: EComponents): T[] {
    return this.components.get(componentName) || [];
  }
}

enum EComponents {
  health = 'health',
}

interface IComponent {
  name: Ecomponents;
}
```

Of course i can use casts, but i don't think that is good idea.
I wanted that type detection work correctly for these methods
My goal in set Map with some name of `EComponent` which keep array of one type `IComponent` like `IHealth` and then transfer it to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed IComponent and create from it generic

```js
interface IComponent<T> {
  name: EComponents;
  id: string;
}

class ComponentStore implements IComponentStore {
  private components: Map<EComponents, IComponent<any>[]> = new Map();

  setComponent<T extends IComponent<T>>( componentName: EComponents, component: IComponent<T>): void {
    const components: IComponent<T>[] = this.components.get(componentName) || [];
    this.components.set(componentName, [...components, component ]);
  }

  getComponents<T extends IComponent<T>>( componentName: EComponents): IComponent<T>[] {
    return this.components.get(componentName) || [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want, but perhaps you can look at something like this:

```
interface EComponents {
  //...
}

interface IComponent {
  //...
}

interface IComponentStore<T extends IComponent> {
  setComponent(componentName: EComponents, component: T): void;
  getComponents(componentName: EComponents): T[];
}

class ComponentStore<T extends IComponent> implements IComponentStore<T> {
  private components = new Map<EComponents, T[]>();

  setComponent(componentName: EComponents, component: T): void {
    const components = this.components.get(componentName) || [];
    this.components.set(componentName, [...components, component ]);
  }

  getComponents(componentName: EComponents): T[] {
    return this.components.get(componentName) || [];
  }
}
```

The idea here is that `ComponentStore` and `IComponentStore` already get the generic type T for the IComponent instances it should handle...

I assumed that `IComponent` and `EComponents` are interfaces. I provided a dummy implementation for them. This code should compile correctly. It generates the following JavaScript (targeting ESNext):

```
"use strict";
class ComponentStore {
    constructor() {
        this.components = new Map();
    }
    setComponent(componentName, component) {
        const components = this.components.get(componentName) || [];
        this.components.set(componentName, [...components, component]);
    }
    getComponents(componentName) {
        return this.components.get(componentName) || [];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

**Edit:**

By the way, `IComponentStore` does not need to be generic for this. The following code works too:

```
interface EComponents {
  //...
}

interface IComponent {
  //...
}

interface IComponentStore {
  setComponent(componentName: EComponents, component: IComponent): void;
  getComponents(componentName: EComponents): IComponent[];
}

class ComponentStore<T extends IComponent> implements IComponentStore {
  private components = new Map<EComponents, T[]>();

  setComponent(componentName: EComponents, component: T): void {
    const components = this.components.get(componentName) || [];
    this.components.set(componentName, [...components, component ]);
  }

  getComponents(componentName: EComponents): T[] {
    return this.components.get(componentName) || [];
  }
}
```

It generates the same JavaScript.

**Edit 2**

Five days have passed since my latest edit. But I promised I would update my answer again based on the new information provided in your comments. Sorry for the delay.

I assume you have already found a fitting answer yourself, but if not, you may perhaps find some inspiration from the following code. Hope it helps.

```
enum EComponents {
  health = 'health',
  wealth = 'wealth'
}

interface IComponent {
  name: EComponents;
  value: string;
}

interface IComponentStore {
  setComponent<T extends IComponent>(component: T): void;
  getComponents<T extends IComponent>(componentName: EComponents): T[];
}

class ComponentStore implements IComponentStore {
  private components: Map<EComponents, IComponent[]> = new Map();

  setComponent<T extends IComponent>(component: T): void {
    const components: IComponent[] = this.components.get(component.name) || [];
    this.components.set(component.name, [...components, component]);
  }

  getComponents<T extends IComponent>(componentName: EComponents): T[] {
    return (this.components.get(componentName) || []) as T[];
  }
}

class Health implements IComponent {
  name: EComponents = EComponents.health;

  constructor(public value: string) {
  }
}

class Wealth implements IComponent {
  name: EComponents = EComponents.wealth;

  constructor(public value: string) {
  }
}

const store = new ComponentStore();

store.setComponent(new Health('ill'));
store.setComponent(new Health('fairly healthy'));
store.setComponent(new Health('top condition'));

store.setComponent(new Wealth('poor'));
store.setComponent(new Wealth('prosperous'));
store.setComponent(new Wealth('filthy rich'));

console.log(store.getComponents(EComponents.health));
console.log(store.getComponents(EComponents.wealth));
```

Comment: Oh, sorry i forgot describe `EComponents` and `IComponent`. I'll edit my question and fix it.
Your approach is not suitable for me, because i want keep all types components in `ComponentStore` and then take array of one type components and handle them in system.

Comment: Thanks. But i wrote about casting types, i don't want to use casting, because it's must to lie to compiler. And i found one solution, i'll write it.